# Translation of natural language to logic

Tags: logic, natural-language-processing

Given a statement in natural language, what can be said about how many possible translations there are in first-order-logic? What happen if we take a more complex logic like second-order logic and what if we take a less complex one?

Comment: Could you be specific about the translation process, and also about the specification of your natural langue. Otherwise, given that NL sentences are often syntactically ambiguous, a precise answer can be: "usually a lot", which will not help you too much.

Comment: I don't see how to properly express the semantics of a statement like "My head feels as if it was Monday" in *any* logic.

Comment: You might try SEP's entry on [Logical Form](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logical-form/) for a background to some of the issues involved; especially relevant are §§2,8-9.

Comment: natural language (in general) includes elements of higher-order logic(s), which are *not* reducable to 1st-order logic